# move objects between containers without copying overhead

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers, move

I have a global vector of object pointers and I'm generating same type of objects and putting them into vector inside a forloop.
That is:

```
vector<object * > ptrVector;
vector<object > objVector;

for ( ; ;)
{
    getElements(objVector);
    calcualte_with(objVector);
    objVector.clear();
}
```

My questions is how can I "move"  objects in objVector into the ptrVector without copying overhead ?

Answer (score 3):

In short, you can't with C++98/C++03. The objects in objVector are allocated and owned by objVector, and when you destruct or clear it the items will also be destructed.

With C++11, you could implement a move constructor for your object and fill ptrVector with new objects that have been move-constructed from the objects in objVector. In general, move constructors move the private members of the object over, avoiding a copy of any large heap-allocated data structure that are owned by the object, which is usually very cheap.

To do that, you'd use something like `std::transform(begin(objVector), end(objVector), std::back_inserter(ptrVector), [](object& o){return new object(std::move(o);})`

However, I'd recommend making ptrVector a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<object>>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<object>>` instead of using a raw pointer if `ptrVector` has exclusive or shared ownership of the objects pointed to by it respectively.

Comment: or better : boost::ptr_container

Answer (score 3):

Short answer - you can't.

`ptrVector` contains pointers, not instances of `object`, so the objects cannot ever be "in" it, by moving them or otherwise, with or without copy overhead.

Objects that are "in" `objVector` can only live beyond `clear()` being called on the vector if `objVector` itself is first swapped with or (in C++11) moved to another instance of `vector<object>`.

Comment: So there is no way to "move" objects in objVector to the heap and put their pointers into the ptrVector before we clean the objVector ?

Comment: @ablimit: well, in C++11 a move constructor can be used to construct an object on the heap, or in C++03 you could create a heap object and then swap it with an element of the vector. This might be cheaper than copying, depending on the class `object`, but it's still a brand new allocation at a different address from the original object. Moving/swapping the whole vector is the only way to "release" the object, as opposed to creating a new object similar to the old one.